# Can an ex-wife's son legally prevent her accessing divorce settlement money?

Tags: talaq, wali

A question that came up during a conversation with some friends. If a woman who has been divorced from her violent husband and through a court of law in the UAE is awarded a certain amount of money from the court, can her now son who apparently has become her guardian stop her from gaining access to what is rightfully hers? Could she go to court to overturn this action from her son?

Comment: There are different views on the order of guardians [Who can be wali and in what order?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39553/who-can-be-wali-and-in-what-order). Of course a court can lift the guardianship from a guardian if he acts against the shari'a or refuses for no good reasons read my answer on [Does the father have to be present during nikah or is his consent enough](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36986/does-the-father-have-to-be-present-during-the-nikah-or-is-his-consent-enough).